# setMap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Feel that understood a lot, but stuck again on new item..
I'm trying to delete marker from the map created with **Google Map API**.
I have a Delete marker button inside the infoWindow.

[image]

There is my code below:

```
function DeleteMarker(index) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(markers[index]));
    markers[index].setMap(null); // problem is here 
    // - setMap is not a function
    markers[index] = null;
}


GMaps.on('click',
    map.map,
    function(event) {

        markers.push(new Point(map.markers.length, event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()));

        var index = map.markers.length;
        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
        var lng = event.latLng.lng();
        map.addMarker({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            title: 'marker' + index,
            infoWindow: {
                content: '<p>Details:'
                + '<p>Latitude:' + event.latLng.lat() +  '</p>'
                + '<p>Longitude:' + event.latLng.lng() + '</p>'+
                '<button id ="btnDeleteMarker" onclick=DeleteMarker(\'' + index + '\')>Delete this stop</button>'
            }
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(markers));
        map.markers[index].infoWindow.open(map.map, map.markers[index]);
});
```

What is wrong? What should I know to use it in a proper way?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: looks like you should be using `map.markers[index].setMap(null)` rather than `markers[index].setMap(null)`

Comment: @geocodezip what do you want to know? I think is minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: @geocodezip I tried. Not working

Comment: There is no HTML/CSS or creation of a map in your posted code.

Comment: @geocodezip you need a Google Map API key anyway to fully recreate the problem.

Comment: That isn't relevant, I have one, but can reproduce without it on jsfiddle and/or in a code snippet (both sites are, at least for the time being, grandfathered on keyless access).

Comment: @geocodezip: Didn't know about the "grandfather keyless" thing... Good to know. Anyway, for the OP submited problem, there was enought details to consider the question as complete and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read on the [Google Map API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove?hl=fr), you have to remove the marker from the `markers array` too.

What I would try, is:

- clear all markers from the map
- remove that marker index
- and then re-draw the markers from what's left in the array.

It would look like this:

```
function DeleteMarker(index) {

    console.log( JSON.stringify(markers[index]) );

    setMapOnAll(null);                  // Clear all markers from the map

    var tempArray = markers;            // Create a temporary array
    unset( tempArray[index] );          // Unset the marker to remove
    markers = array_values(tempArray);  // refresh the markers array

    setMapOnAll(map);                   // Show all markers on the map

}
```

I did not test this... I would have to create a map for it.
But I will if the above code fails.
;)

Comment: yeap, I got how to fix. Thanks a lot!